# How to break the loop in Golang

Tags: go

I'm learning programming using Go. The following program should continuously display menu until 0 is chosen. Current behavior: If the users first choice is 0, loop breaks. If first time the choice was 1, 2 or 3, the second time when 0 is chosen, loop doesn't break. What am I doing wrong?

```
            package main
            import "fmt"

            func main() {
                multiline2 :=   "Welcome! Please make your choice: \n" +
                                "--------------------------------- \n" +
                                "1. Option One \n" +
                                "2. Option Two \n" +
                                "3. Option Three \n" +
                                "0. Exit \n" +
                                "----------------- \n" +
                                "Your Choice is: "
                fmt.Print(multiline2)
                var usersChoice int
                fmt.Scanln(&usersChoice)
                decider(usersChoice)
            }

            func decider(value int) {
                testLoop:for value > 0 {
                    switch value {
                    case 1:
                        fmt.Println("You Chose One, try again \n")
                        //break
                        main()
                    case 2:
                        fmt.Println("You Chose Two, try again \n")
                        //break
                        main()
                    case 3:
                        fmt.Println("You Chose Three, try again \n")
                        //break
                        main()
                    case 0:
                        fmt.Println("You Chose To Quit")
                        fmt.Println("Good Bye")
                        value = 0   // doesnt help...
                        break testLoop
                    }
                }
            }
```

---

### After Updates this is the working code in case if it helps someone.

```
        package main
        import "fmt"

        func main() {
            starter()
        }

        func starter() {
            multiline2 :=   "Welcome! Please make your choice: \n" +
                            "--------------------------------- \n" +
                            "1. Option One \n" +
                            "2. Option Two \n" +
                            "3. Option Three \n" +
                            "0. Exit \n" +
                            "----------------- \n" +
                            "Your Choice is: "
            fmt.Print(multiline2)
            var usersChoice int
            fmt.Scanln(&usersChoice)
            decider(usersChoice)
        }

        func decider(value int) {
              //for value > 0 {
                switch value {
                case 1:
                    fmt.Println("You Chose One, try again \n")
                    starter()
                case 2:
                    fmt.Println("You Chose Two, try again \n")
                    starter()
                case 3:
                    fmt.Println("You Chose Three, try again \n")
                    starter()
                case 0:
                    fmt.Println("You Chose To Quit")
                    fmt.Println("Good Bye")
                    //value = 0
                    //break
                }
            //}
        }
```

Comment: fyi, `main` is not to be called directly, you want to reuse behavior in main? move that behaviour into its own function and call that directly.

Comment: if the user chooses 0 there is nothing to break since the loop will not run, why will it not run? because you set the loop's condition to `value > 0`.

Comment: I moved everything inside main to another function, "starter", now inside main I just call starter() function. But this did not solve the problem. Still cannot break that loop. But thank for your comment I will note that main should not be recalled like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't call "main" from inside a for loop like that; when you do it, you're asking for the user input again, but the calling code is still iside that loop, so it will keep running it again. You should just remove that "for" loop at all (and "break testLoop" as well).

Comment: Removing the "for" loop should solve the problem you asked here. As you decided to refactor your code, you now have a different problem, please ask a separate question on StackOverflow.

Comment: If I remove for loop, menu is not shown after choosing 1,2,3. It needs to be printed again.

Comment: It is still shown, I tested it here. Just remove 3 lines from your original code and you're good to go: "testLoop: for value > 0", "break testLoop", and the "for" ending bracket.

Comment: So it appears there is no need for any loop to continuously print menu. Calling the function again after the desired choice does the magic.  Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the for loop in the decider function.

Whenever your decider function runs if value is not 0, it calls main, but the loop for that decider function call is still running. So the next time 0 is passed, nothing is run for the second call of the decider function, so it exits. Note that the loop for the first call is still running (in that call the value passed is whatever was passed in by the user the first time) hence your loop never exits.

```
func decider(value int) {
    switch value {
    case 1:
        fmt.Println("You Chose One, try again \n")
        //break
        main()
    case 2:
        fmt.Println("You Chose Two, try again \n")
        //break
        main()
    case 3:
        fmt.Println("You Chose Three, try again \n")
        //break
        main()
    case 0:
        fmt.Println("You Chose To Quit")
        fmt.Println("Good Bye")
        value = 0 // doesnt help...
    }
}
```

Comment: fyi, prolly a bad idea to call main directly.